# Where/how do I configure the content of the Paypal IPN notification email in Joomla

Tags: joomla, paypal-ipn

I have taken over a site from someone else who set up a Paypal account connected to OSE Membership on a Joomla site.

The Joomla site sends me an email from the Admin address which contains a Paypal IPN notification.  Where and how how do I find this set up and configure the content of the Paypal IPN notification email in Joomla?  I want to add fields/graphics, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla by default doesn't have PayPal IPN built in.  It might a module or plugin that you are using with Joomla, or a shopping cart.  You could start by looking at your modules and plugins.  You could try checking your PayPal account, and your IPN settings to see if it is set in your PayPal account.  That would tell you where the actual IPN file is on your server.